# Pass query params to an endpoint in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am new to rest assured and I have some requests which I want to do as a part of rest assured I have the query parameters to be passed in the request as test data dynamically without hard coding it. These are my requests.

1. {{Base_Url}}/master-data/v1/calendars/GBL?from=2022-11-29&to=2022-11-30&monthEnd=true
2. {{Base_Url}}/master-data/v1/calendars/GBL?from=2022-11-29&to=2022-11-30&monthEnd=false

Normally in rest assured we pass query params as

```
Response res = httpRequest.queryParam("ISBN","9781449325862").get("/Book");
```

But in my case the query parameters are a bit complicated like GBL?from=2022-11-29&to=2022-11-30&monthEnd=true and these aren't straight forward. How to handle these in rest assured?

Comment: The answer provided by Lucas should work. You need few query params not one so you can provide them as map of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do that.

1. Use `queryParam()`

```java
Response res = httpRequest
                 .queryParam("from","2022-11-29")
                 .queryParam("to","2022-11-30")
                 .queryParam("monthEnd",true)
                 .get("/master-data/v1/calendars/GBL");
```

2. Use `Map<String, ?>`

```java
//work for java 11
Map<String, ?> params = Map.of("from", "2022-11-29", "to", "2022-11-30", "monthEnd", true);

Response res = httpRequest
                 .queryParams(params)
                 .get("/master-data/v1/calendars/GBL");
```